# Stuck on inductive step: $2^x > x^n$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, inequality, induction

I want to show that $2^x > x^n$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm trying to do it by induction over $n$. The base case, $n = 1$, is true: $2^x > x$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$. After assuming $2^x > x^n$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$, I can't work out any idea to infer $2^x > x^{n + 1}$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$.
I tried $2^x > x^n$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ implies that $2^x \cdot 2^x > x^n \cdot x^n > x^{n+1}$, but on the left side there is still an extra "$2^x$" bothering me. How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your calculation, we have from the induction hypothesis
$$2^{2x} =2^x\cdot 2^x \gt x^{2n}$$
for large enough $x$. We need to show that for large enough $x$, we have $x^{2n}\ge (2x)^{n+1}$. Equivalently, we want to show that $x^{n-1}\ge 2^{n+1}$ for large enough $x$. Pick $x\ge 8$. Then $x^{n-1}\ge 2^{3n-3}$. This is $\ge 2^{n+1}$ if $n\ge 2$.

**Remark:** There are many ways to solve the problem without induction. A very "calculusy" way is to take the logarithm of both sides. Then the problem reduces to showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$. This can be done using L'Hospital's Rule, and in other ways.

Comment: Something seems wrong here:  $2^{2x}\gt(2x)^{n+1}$ doesn't simplify to $2^x\gt x^{n+1}$.

Comment: It is not intended to simplify. We have $2^{2x}\gt x^{2n}$ for large $x$. If I can show that $x^{2n}\ge (2x)^{n+1}$, then I will know that for large $x$, we have $2^{2x}\gt (2x)^{n+1}$, that is, $2^y\gt y^{n+1}$ for large $y$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you :) So the point was to see that $x^{n-1}\ge 2^{n+1}$ for large enough $x$.

Comment: You are welcome. And it doesn't have to be large, $8$ is good enough. However, we were using the induction assumption, and for $n+1$ our crude estimate for "large enough" doubled. By looking at details of the argument, one could give an explicit bound on how large is (plenty) large enough, for given $n$. Note there are plenty of other ways to prove the desired result, such as the Binomial Theorem.